# How do we connect many microcontrollers together?

Tags: wifi, web-server

My group project consists of several parts.

We are building a hexapod robot that detects landmines and we program live streaming on it. For the live streaming the Raspberry Pi is used and for the hexapod robot and the metal detections the Tiva LaunchPad, Mbed and Basic atom are used.

The hexapod robot needs to be controlled from a web page. A Wi-Fi USB will be connected on the Raspberry Pi to transmit data back to the web page. I am building the web page with HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

I will probably use Apache as a web server and execute Python (for Raspberry Pi) using WSGI (even though I'm not quite sure how to do any of these).

Now, my question is how do we execute the rest of the coding from the rest of the microcontrollers? Should we connect the microcontrolers using SPI and then transmit the data only from the Raspberry Pi? But if we do so, how can we translate the code, since it is written in different languages.

If you have had any experience with similar projects please help.

Comment: Welcome to raspberrypi.SE. I'd say, get the bot walking first. Then about how to control it using the command line. Then you can worry about the web page. There are also gigabytes of tutorials about how to do this on the webz. Input "raspberry pi robot web interface" into your favourite web search tool and have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pre-program all microcontrollers before letting this system into the wild. Assuming you have done this you can use any communication protocol you like, SPI, I<sup>2</sup>C (my personal favourite) or maybe CAN.

Language does not make a difference as all the microcontrollers (and the Pi) are doing is talking over a bunch of bus wires. Just make sure all your devices speak the same language - use the same protocol.

Comment: what do you mean pre-program all microcontrollers? how do we do this?

Comment: @Anna I recommend against latting microcontrollers load profram out in the wild. Microcontrollers are unlike processors like Raspberry Pi that can load a program upon request - they run one firmware from beginning to the end.